# homotopy of a real projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology

By Seifert-Van Kampen theorem, $\pi_1(P) = \mathbb Z/2$. If $a$ is a generator of the group, this means that $aa = 1$. In terms of homotopy, this implies that $c_{x_0} \cong w*w$, where $w \in a$ is a loop. How can I visually construct homotopy between these two paths? i.e. make a square-like diagram, where the $x$-axis represents the space $P$ and $y$-axis represents time interval.

Comment: Do the answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629595/fundamental-group-of-projective-plane-is-c-2?rq=1 help?

Comment: Which definition of $P$ do you use?

Comment: @paul The picture looks like: draw a circle, and points are identified antipodally. The disk with quotient topology is P. So, the edges along the hemisphere represent $a$. I haven’t had time to look at Best’s link above yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q : D^2 \to P$ be the quotient map which identifies antipodal points of $S^1$.  We can regard $P$ as the adjunction space $D^2 \cup_\phi S^1$, where $\phi : S^1 \to S^1, \phi(z) = z^2$.

Let $u : [0,1] \to D^2, u(t) = e^{\pi it}$ and $v : [0,1] \to D^2, v(t) = -e^{\pi it}$. Then $q \circ u = q \circ v$. Let us denote this map by $w : [0,1] \to P$. It is a loop based at $q(1)$ representing the generator of $\pi_1(P,q(1))$. The path $\gamma = u * v$ is a loop in $D^2$ (it runs once counterclockwise around $S^1 \subset D^2$) based at $1 \in S^1$ and
$$H: [0,1] \times  [0,1] \to D^2, H(t,s) = (1-s)\gamma(t)+ s$$
is a path homotopy to the constant path based at $1$. Consider the homotopy $H' = q \circ H : [0,1] \times  [0,1] \to P$. This is a homotopy of paths in $P$. We have $H'(t,0) = q \circ (u * v) = (q \circ u) * (q \circ u) = w * w$ and $H'(t,1) = q(1)$.

This proves your claim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Paul. One thing that I haven’t understood is, is the homotopy well-defined? First, $H$ is a homotopy on $D^2$ that is equivalent to a straight path between $\gamma(t)$ and $1 \in S^1$. For fixed $t_0 \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, the $H(t_0, s)$  and $H(t_0 + \frac{1}{2}, s)$ are two distinct paths. Going back to $P$, since antipodal points on the circle are identified together, $\gamma(t) \sim \gamma(t+\frac{1}{2})$. Thus, $H’(t_0, 0) = H’(t_0+\frac{1}{2}, 0)$. This implies that $H’(t_0, s) = H’(t_0 + \frac{1}{2}, s)$ for every $s \in I$. However, they are different paths!

Comment: I mean, if $s \in (0, 1)$, then I already know that $H(t_0, s) \neq H(t_0 + \frac{1}{2}, s)$ (they lie on interior of the disk, and they are different points.) Thus, $q \circ H(t_0, s) = H(t_0, s) \neq H(t_0 + \frac{1}{2}, s) = q \circ H(t_0 + \frac{1}{2}, s)$, contradiction.

Comment: Given $\gamma$, the only thing we have to know is $H(0,s) = H(1,s)$ for all $s$. This is true because $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$. It means that $H$ is a homotopy of paths in $D^2$. And whatever $H$ does, we can project it via $q$ to $P$.

Comment: Yes, I was ignoring a basic fact that $q \circ H$ is a composition of continuous map, so it defines a homotopy on $P$. Nevertheless, I am confused about the counterintuitive behavior that I described. I try to visualize homotopy by tracing a path that a particle moves along. The particle here is $\gamma(t_0) = \gamma(t_0 + \frac{1}{2})$. However, one particle cannot move along two distinct paths. Is such phenomenon happening because $\gamma$ is not an injective path?

Comment: $\gamma$ is in fact not injective, but the only two points of $[0,1]$ having the same image under $\gamma$ are $0$ and $1$. But the point is that for **any two closed paths** $\gamma, \delta : [0,1] \to D^2$ based at the same $x \in D^2$ we get $\gamma \simeq \delta$ by $H(t,s) = (1-s)\gamma(t) + s \delta(t)$, simply because $D^2$ is convex.

Comment: Just a final comment, $q \circ \gamma$ is injective, right? $q \circ \gamma(t_0) = q \circ \gamma(t_0 + \frac{1}{2})$. (To be fair, I said $\gamma$ is injective earlier, not that $q \circ \gamma$ is injective.)

Comment: No, $q \circ \gamma$ is not injective: As you say, $q \circ \gamma(t_0) = q \circ \gamma(t_0 +1/2)$. This is obviuous because we want $q \circ \gamma = w  * w$. And, by the way, no closed path can be inijective since it maps $0, 1$ to the same point. But this is a "trivial" non-injectivity which is due to closedness.

Comment: oh god. I am have been thinking “non-injectivity” all the time and typed out the word “injective” instead. I have no idea what I have been thinking. Thank you for the answer.